# Load PFobject in multiple views

Tags: swift, parse-platform, segue, pfobject, pass-data

In one view it creates a PFObject, then passes this Object to another view via prepareforsegue. I am wanting this PFObject to be available to read without the prepare for seque passing the data first. is this possible in swift please, thanks

Comment: As far as i know what you are doing is the most recommended approach, you could store them in seperate class as static but it could bring more troubles like memory leak...

Comment: indeed, but I am needing the object to be passed to a detail view of the initial detail view as I have a 'more' button which I wish to read from the same database. @MazelTov